Sitecore 10 Forms , Custom Submit Action , Saving Form Data & CD Server Issue
I am using Sitecore 10 Forms (Contact us) with Angular JSS.
On Submit Button I have created "Custom Submit Action" in Sitecore and it is working fine.
I want to Save the Form Data in Separate Template , On my Local machine it is working fine as CM and CD are on same machine, but when I pushed the code to Staging/Production it is not working as Database.GetDatabase("master") is not accessed in CD Server.
When I use Sitecore.Context.Database , it is getting as Web database and data is Saved in Web Database not in master db. I think it is not good to save data directly on Web Database.
I have read somewhere we can use EventQueue for this type of data Insertion in both master & web databases.
I want to Save data first and master and publish from code to web and trigger some email that data is saved.
But As I can access master database in Submit action , I can't able to save data in master.
here is the code for Event Queue in Custom Submit Action.
                    PostRequestEvent evt = new PostRequestEvent();
                    evt.Value = serializedObj;

                    _logger.Info("Calling Event Queue at: " + DateTime.Now, this);

                    var eventQueue = new Sitecore.Eventing.DefaultEventQueueProvider()
                        .GetEventQueues()
                        .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("master")).FirstOrDefault();

I have created Handler,update the config patch but no luck.
Does anybody Save data like or anyone has some example which is related to this.
I will love to check. :)

Why do you create Sitecore items? There is default Save Data action which saves data into Forms database

Yes I know, I need for some other purpose to save data in other Items.
Or you suggest some other work around?

Why do you want to save data in 2 places? Can't you read it from forms database if you need to use it later?

You can use the Remote Events to create items in the Master DB on demand.
A high level approach based on a Remote Event supported by Sitecore out-of-the-box will be as follows:

CM instance is subscribed to a Remote Event (say
"form-submission:created" and "form-submission:created:remote" event definitions).
On a form submission CD instance will add a new
Remote Event to the Event Queue.
CM instance listens the Event Queue
and executes it. Note, that by default all instances listen the
Event Queue, but the execution is driven by a subscription model,
therefore, CD will never execute it as it doesn't have the required
configuration.

More useful information and code examples can be found here.
